# How to insert in append ROWS separated data using Google SpreadSheet and Python

Tags: python, pandas, google-sheets-api, spreadsheet

I need to insert different data on different instances, and put them on ROWS (excel).
I saw the documentation about how to insert those data, but I didnt get it to work.

I saw this guide:
https://medium.com/@jb.ranchana/write-and-append-dataframes-to-google-sheets-in-python-f62479460cf0

I understand that the initial point is always A1, and because of that it always inserts data on A1, but im having trouble specifying the initial position.

Inserting data as:

```
`df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['apple'], 'b': ['banana'], 'c': ['cantaloupe']})
```

I have no trouble.

```
However, when I insert them like:
    df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['apple']})
    df = pd.DataFrame({'b': ['banana']})
    df = pd.DataFrame({'c': ['cantaloupe']})
```

They all go on A1, when I need for example:
ROW B(col1,col2,col3,col4)

(Of course, im inserting those separate data correctly and not overwriting any of them. I take apple and send it to the spreadsheet before I use banana.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between your showing script and Google Spreadsheet. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: Im sendig the data to an Excel of GoogleSpreadSheet. I just need to know, how can I set positions of data before sending them, because the default position is the ROW A. So I need, instead of it inserting as 
Apple: (COLUMN A, ROW 1), banana (COLUMN A, ROW 2), cantaloupe (COLUMN A, ROW 3)

Insert it as: 
Apple: (COLUMN A, ROW 1), banana (COLUMN B, ROW 1), cantaloupe (COLUMN C, ROW 1)

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `Excel of GoogleSpreadSheet.`, in this case, I cannot understand you want to use XLSX data or Google Spreadsheet. Which do you want to use? And, if you want to use Google Spreadsheet, how do you want to upload the data using Sheets API? For example, you want to use googleapis for python or gspread for python? And, you want to put the values of `Apple`, `banana` and `cantaloupe` to one row and 3 columns instead of 3 rows and 1 column. Is my understanding correct?